# Calculating the points of accumulation of the inverse image $(f^{-1}(0))'$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I would like to ask you something that still has me a little intrigued.

Maybe mine is a silly question, but I still can't get out of it.

I am analyzing the following function:

$f:\begin{array}{rcl}
B(0,1) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{C}  \\
z & \longmapsto & \cos\left ( \frac{1+z}{1-z} \right ) 
\end{array}$

to obtain that

$f^{-1}(0)=\left \{ \frac{(2n+1)\pi-2}{(2n+1)\pi+2} \Big| n\in\mathbb{Z}                         \right \}\subseteq B(0,1)$

I want to calculate the accumulation points of $f^{-1}(0)$  i.e  $(f^{-1}(0))'$.

Initially, what I did was to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ y $\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty}$, asi $1\in (f^{-1}(0))'$. Confirming that $1$ is the only accumulation point by visualizing the chart.

And this is where my question comes in, how do I ensure without visualizing the graph that this is in fact my only accumulation point, assuming I haven't found them all $(f^{-1}(0))'$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $a_n:=\frac{(2n+1)\pi-2}{(2n+1)\pi+2}$ converges towards $1$ for $n\longrightarrow\pm\infty$, since
$$\frac{(2n+1)\pi-2}{(2n+1)\pi+2} = \frac{n}{n}\cdot\frac{2\pi+\frac{\pi-2}{n}}{2\pi + \frac{\pi +2}{n}}\longrightarrow \frac{2\pi}{2\pi}=1.$$
Thus, the only accumulation point of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is $1$, and the same of course follows for the set $\{a_n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.